# How to get the average of vectors in lists having same names inside for loop in R

Tags: r

Here is the small example of what i am trying to do.

```
ex1 <- c(1,2,3)
nm <- c("cone","ctwo","cthree") 
names(ex1) <- nm

ex2 <- c(1.3,1.5,1.6)
names(ex2) <- nm

ex3 <- c(1.4,1.6,1.8)
names(ex3) <- nm

ex <- list(ex1,ex2,ex3)

for (i in seq(ex))
{
   ab<- ex[[i]]
}
```

The output i am getting is:

```
  ab
  cone   ctwo cthree 
  1.4    1.6    1.8
```

But the expected output should be something like this.

```
  ab
  cone   ctwo cthree 
  1.233    1.7    2.133
```

It gives the average values of cone ctwo and cthree from the three vectors in the list.

Comment: The solution suggested works only for this particular example but I have a large list having more than 100 elements generated. To enter all these manually will be tedious. That is the reason i want iterate over for loop.

Comment: It is not clear when you say that the list have more than 100 elements.  It can have 100 or 1000 or 10000 elements, doesn't matter, the method suggested is to `rbind` the elements and then get the `colMeans`

Comment: Basically `ex <- list(ex1,ex2,ex3)` step will be done with `mget(paste0("ex", 1:3))` or `mget(ls(pattern = "^ex\\d+$"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `colMeans` after `rbind`ing the `list` elements

```
colMeans(do.call(rbind, ex))
#    cone     ctwo   cthree 
#1.233333 1.700000 2.133333
```

If we have objects created in the global environment with name starting with 'ex' followed by numbers, get all of them in a `list` with `mget` and then apply the code as above

```
colMeans(do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = "ex\\d+"))))
```

---

Or using `Reduce`

```
Reduce(`+`, ex)/length(ex)
```

---

Or using a `for` loop

```
n <- length(ex)
v1 <- numeric(n)
for(i in seq_along(ex)) v1 <- v1 + ex[[i]]
v1/m
```

Comment: The solution you gave will work for this particular example. But the example i provided was very naive. I want to use for loop. My list is a very big list.

Comment: @AbhijeetPatil  If the column names are the same.  This would be more efficient than a `for` loop

Comment: I have a large list having more than 100 elements generated. To enter all these manually will be tedious. That is the reason i want iterate over for loop

Comment: @AbhijeetPatil  Not sure why you need to enter manually, when you already have a `list`.  If the objects are individually creaated then `colMeans(do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = "ex\\d+"))))`

Comment: The for loop you suggested works perfectly fine in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Another way will be this:

```
> rowMeans(data.frame(ex))
    cone     ctwo   cthree 
1.233333 1.700000 2.133333
```

Answer (score 2):

Name your list elements in `ex`:

```
ex <- list(ex1 = ex1, ex2 = ex2, ex3 = ex3)
```

then find the mean row-wise:

```
apply(as.data.frame(ex), 1, mean)

    cone     ctwo   cthree 
1.233333 1.700000 2.133333
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps computationally slow but we can use `plyr`:

```
 sapply(plyr::ldply(ex),mean)
    cone     ctwo   cthree 
1.233333 1.700000 2.133333
```